# How to use P4Merge tool with SVN 1.8 merge files?

Tags: svn, p4merge

I did an svn merge and I get 3 files, namely,

```
somefile.xml.working
somefile.xml.left.12345
somefile.xml.right.12350
```

When I launch the P4Merge tool, i have 3 text fields, named, Base, 1st file, and 2nd file. Which file goes to which box? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it indirectly answered my question.
http://1024strongoxen.blogspot.com/2011/08/three-way-merging-made-painless-with.html

Per the article, I setup TurtoiseSVN to use P4Merge. When I launched TurtoiseSVN's conflict resolution window (Right-click-file->Edit conflicts), it assigned the following.

```
Base: somefile.xml.left.12345
Left: somefile.xml.right.12350
Right: somefile.xml.working
```